# Make syntax shorter when using if & else with statements

Tags: c#, .net

I'm currently working on a dll library project.

```
if (!Directory.Exists(MenGinPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(MenGinPath + @"TimedMessages");
    File.WriteAllLines(MenGinPath + @"TimedMessages\timedmessages.txt", new string[] { "Seperate each message with a new line" });
}
else if (!File.Exists(MenGinPath + @"TimedMessages\timedmessages.txt"))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(MenGinPath + @"TimedMessages");
    File.WriteAllLines(MenGinPath + @"TimedMessages\timedmessages.txt", new string[] { "Seperate each message with a new line" });
}
```

As you can see if the statement `Directory.Exists` is false a specific directory (`MenGinPath`) will be created. However, if the same path, with another file in addition is false, the second functions will be called.

**My question is the following: is there any way to make this shorter?**

Because as you can see I'm calling 2 times the same functions:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(MenGinPath + @TimedMessages\timedmessages.txt
```

and

```
File.WriteAllLines(MenGinPath + @"\TimedMessages\timedmessages.txt"))
```

Any help would be welcome!!

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Please post an [mcve]

Comment: @Steve how's that? I compiled it with no problem.

Comment: @Steve btw the WriteLog is a method I made myself if that's what ur tryna get

Comment: Not possible. That code contains an else if without a proper if before it. The compiler stops with a missing } at the first WriteAllLines

Comment: @Selrygoxeser There is no way you got the compiler to accept an `else` not attached to an `if`.

Comment: @Steve sorry, something went wrong when copying I think I've changed it btw

Comment: Now it makes sense. But in the else if you use CreateDirectory with the name of the file.

Comment: @Steve ye I've seen lol, I've changed it lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check if directory exists because [Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) automatically creates the directory if it does not exists and does nothing if the directory already exists.

Also, do not include the filename when creating the directory. Yes, it wont error but just for clarity sake.

Another one is to use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of hardcoding the path. This will improve readability of your code.

So, here's what I can come up with:

```
string dir = Path.Combine(MenGinPath, @"Groups\TimesMessages");
string file = Path.Combine(dir, "timedmessages.txt");

// this automatically creates all directories in specified path
// unless it already exists
Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);

//of course, you still need to check if the file exists
if (!File.Exists(file) {
   File.WriteAllLines(filePath, new string[] { "Seperate each message with a new line" });
}
/* or if file exists, do your stuff (optional)
* else {
*  //do something else? maybe edit the file?
* }
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can make your code shorter given the fact that [CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) does nothing when the directory exists. Moreover do not pullute your code with all that string concatenations to create the path and the file names.
Just do it one time before entering the logic using the appropriate method to create filenames and pathnames ([Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
string messagePath = Path.Combine(MenGinPath, "TimedMessages");
string fileName = Path.Combine(messagePath, "timedmessages.txt");

// call the create even if it exists. The CreateDirectory checks the fact
// by itself and thus, if you add your own check, you are checking two times.
Directory.CreateDirectory(messagePath);

if (!File.Exists(fileName)
     File.WriteAllLines(fileName, new string[] { "Seperate each message with a new line" });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add that `Directory.CreateDirectory` will create the entire directory structure if needed?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto correct, honestly I haven't thought about it. Probably because in the context of the question it seems unrelated. In any case the link provided explains also that point.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only difference between the 2 cases is the path. So just get only this path in your if-else

```
const string GroupsPath = @"Groups\timedmessages.txt";
const string TimedMessagesTxt = @"TimedMessages\TimedMessages.txt";

string addPath = null;
if (!Directory.Exists(MenGinPath)) {
    addPath = GroupsPath;
} else if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(MenGinPath, TimedMessagesTxt))) {
    addPath = TimedMessagesTxt;
}
If (addPath != null) {
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(MenGinPath,  addPath));
    File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(MenGinPath, TimedMessagesTxt),
        new string[] { "Seperate each message with a new line" });
}
```

Note: Using `Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation has the advantage that missig or extra `\` are added or removed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
string strAppended = string.Empty;
if (!Directory.Exists(MenGinPath))
{
    strAppended = MenGinPath + @"Groups\timedmessages.txt";
}
else if (!File.Exists(MenGinPath + @"TimedMessages\timedmessages.txt"))
{
    strAppended = MenGinPath + @"TimedMessages\TimedMessages.txt";
}
else
{
    return;
}
Directory.CreateDirectory(strAppended);
File.WriteAllLines(strAppended, new string[] { "Seperate each message with a new line" });
```

I have found that it is a great idea to reuse blocks of code like this instead of hiding them in if statements because it makes code maintenance and debugging easier and less prone to missed bugs.